# What macros do I have to invoke to get the day of month, month, and year?

Tags: macros, datetime

What macros do I have to invoke to get the day of month, month, and year of the current date? I am a beginner in LaTeX.

Comment: `\the\day--\the\month--\the\year`?

Comment: @Manuel: Oh you got it.  What is the next thing you will do?

Comment: You're a beginner in LaTeX?

Comment: @Sverre: Just to fool the system to increase the quality of my question.

Comment: I don't think "the system" has any way of estimating the quality of your question. Are you asking because you actually didn't know the macros, or are you asking because you think there should be a question-answer about this on TeX.sX? I'm just a bit confused about what you're up to here.

Comment: @Sverre: Try making the title and body of your question short but exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\the\day--\the\month--\the\year
```

In case you want a verbose month, I think it's done in LaTeX with

```
\ifcase\month\or
  January\or
  February\or
  March\or
  April\or
  May\or
  June\or
  July\or
  August\or
  September\or
  October\or
  November\or
  December\fi
```

(Not sure if I wrote them correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Koma-Script package `scrdate`.
[Documentation of Koma-Script, look for scrdate](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

Example Commands:

```
\DayName{year}{month}{day}
\ISODayName{ISO-date}
\ISOToday
\todaysname
\todaysnumber
```